# Are there central theories on aesthetics?

Tags: aesthetics

Are there central theories on aesthetics? I am looking to see if there were any significant philosophers by significant I mean people who often are discussed among university circles today or in the past who espoused the view that art can be appraised objectively by a set of guiding principles that judge the aesthetic value of art. Is there any philosopher you could recommend? What are some consensus or leading opinion on the subject in general?

Comment: "There is no special way works of art have to be. And that is the present and, I should say, the final moment in the master narrative. It is the end of the story." says [Danto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Danto) sorry if that's unhelpful...

Comment: Look at [SEP Philosophical Conceptions of Beauty](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/beauty/#ObjSub) and references there. I don't know about "central", but there is a tradition going back to Aristotle and Kant. But be careful, "appraised objectively" is too strong, judgments of taste are clearly subjective in part. The best you can hope for is *some* objective aspects.